# Why are wide binary systems assumed to contain negligible dark matter?

Tags: astrophysics, dark-matter, modified-gravity, binary-stars

I'm doing a project that simulates wide binaries to do gravity tests, specifically a dark matter vs MOND test. I've come across similar papers, and their justification for using wide binaries for this test is often "wide binaries are generally presumed to contain negligible dark matter" (ex: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09619) 
I'm wondering, why can we assume that wide binaries contain negligible dark matter?

Answer (score 2):

It would be more proper to state that binaries are generally presumed to contain a negligible gradient in dark matter density. That statement is the same for our Solar System, or any structure at such "small" scales. Dark matter has no strong interaction, in particular no dissipative force, can thus not shed angular momentum, and therefore not form compact objects. For the same reason dark matter halos are rather puffy and much larger than the galaxies they surround. That said, there still is a basically uniform dark matter background density in binaries, solar systems, or other such small scales, but a constant density does not induce much of a gravitational effect (up to corrections in the post-Newtonian limit).

Comment: FWIW, according to [Ethan Siegel](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2018/03/24/ask-ethan-if-dark-matter-is-everywhere-why-havent-we-detected-it-in-our-solar-system/), the mass of dark matter in our Solar System, out to the orbit of Neptune, is around $10^{17}$ kg, which is the mass of a rocky asteroid of ~20 km radius. So even if all the dark matter in a binary system of that separation (the diameter of Neptune's orbit) *were* concentrated into a lump its affect on the stars' motion would be negligible.

Comment: True. BTW, on reading this again, I was also connecting that the stability of wide binary systems is used to place upper-mass-limits on dark matter... somewhere lighter than a few solar masses.